# Insert into ASPxGridView with Cascading DropDowns

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I am using DevExpress Gridview for making CRUD operations,
I am following [this](https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/gridediting/CascadingComboBoxes.aspx) link. And Update operation working fine.

I want to Insert new rows, So I added properties in Gridview, And it shows create button.

The problem is, In new row, When I change country it's not updating City automatically. It is calling JavaScript function after changing Country dropdown, But not calling C# code function.

Below is my grid code,

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                    ClientSideEvents-Init="OnInit" 
                    DataSourceID="dsMasterDataList"
                    ClientInstanceName="gvMasterDataList"
                    ID="gvMasterDataList" 
                    KeyFieldName="ID"
                    OnBatchUpdate="GvMasterDataList_BatchUpdate" 
                    OnCellEditorInitialize="gvMasterDataList_CellEditorInitialize" 
                    OnCommandButtonInitialize="gvMasterDataList_CommandButtonInitialize"
                    OnRowDeleted="gvMasterDataList_RowDeleted" 
                    OnRowInserted="gvMasterDataList_RowInserted" 
                    OnRowUpdated="gvMasterDataList_RowUpdated" 
                    OnRowValidating="gvMasterDataList_RowValidating"
                    OnSummaryDisplayText="gvMasterDataList_SummaryDisplayText" 
                    runat="server" >
<SettingsEditing Mode="Inline" />
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ButtonType="Image" Caption=" " FixedStyle="Left" ShowClearFilterButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowNewButtonInHeader="true" Width="32" />
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowEditButton="true" Caption=" " ShowClearFilterButton="true" />
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" Visible="false" />
..
..
```

Where I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to omit the following conditions inside the "grid_CellEditorInitialize" event handler:

CS:

```
//if(!grid.IsEditing || e.Column.FieldName != "City") return;
//if(e.KeyValue == DBNull.Value || e.KeyValue == null) return;
```

VB:

```
'If (Not grid.IsEditing) OrElse e.Column.FieldName <> "City" Then
'   Return
'End If
'If e.KeyValue Is DBNull.Value OrElse e.KeyValue Is Nothing Then
'   Return
'End If
```

They are always true for a "New" mode and skip the rest code logic.

Check out a self-contained db-independent solution at [E3689](https://www.devexpress.com/example=E3689) instead.